My grid cannot be found in pageSource for automation test using WinAppDriver
I have a winforms project which uses clgride / clrow / etc. However, I cannot find the related elements in the real pageSource, so I cannot fetch the cell and fill in data.
Could you share how I can change my app config to enable these celss can be visible in the pageSource with correct AutomationId?
Thanks a lot,
I tried to change some fields in my winforms project like visible = true, but the issue is still there
